# dynamically choose filters/fields in an aggregation table on a View

Tags: views, panels, theming

I need users to customize which kind of aggregation to apply to a table (view).

Example: let´s choose counts of species X and Y in an area. This means apply two filters. 
          I also want to give the option to choose fields 'species', 'area' and 'place'. The table resulting of applying these 3 filters would give a completely different table than before.

Insert all the (3) filters into the same view creates allways the same result. I don't think there is some way of let user choose 'disabling' one of the filters.

Should I create two different views (each one with its corresponding filters) inserted into a panel or there is some better way to solve that?

To make more clear, here are two screenshots:

1) Without 'Place' field (and filter): for especie Cuniculus paca, number of counts is 60.

[image]

2) With'Place' field: as for each especie we have different places names, the results are completely different.

[image]

In fact I think the question should not be exclusively about filters but also about Views.

There is a chance to avoid a Field to be 'executed' (applied to the resulting View) allways? 'Exclude from Display' with Aggregation options YES doesn't do any effect, the results are grouped by this new field also, changing completely all the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the filters (and for markup and additional functionality, there is a nice module [Better exposed filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)). You can find it when adding a filter "Expose this filter to visitors, allow tthem to change it", under the advanced sction on the right (by default collapsed) you can group them into a block and then add them to your site whereever you need them.

Hope I understood the question the right way.